# Adding CommandLogger to MongoClient - monitoring

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have MongoClient from PyMongo.I do not know how to add a event_listener to an existing MongoClient. This is what I have:

from pymongo import MongoClient, monitoring

class CommandLogger(monitoring.CommandListener):
    def started(self, event):
        logging.info("Command {0.command_name} with request id "
                     "{0.request_id} started on server "
                     "{0.connection_id}".format(event))

```
def succeeded(self, event):
    logging.info("Command {0.command_name} with request id "
                 "{0.request_id} on server {0.connection_id} "
                 "succeeded in {0.duration_micros} "
                 "microseconds".format(event))

def failed(self, event):
    logging.error("Command {0.command_name} with request id "
                 "{0.request_id} on server {0.connection_id} "
                 "failed in {0.duration_micros} "
                 "microseconds".format(event))

monitoring.register(CommandLogger())

def get_mongo_client():
    ...
    ...
    my_mongo_client = MongoClient(connString)

   # Here, I want to add a event_listener - something like this:
   # my_mongo_client = MongoClient(connString, event_listeners=[CommandLogger()])
    return my_mongo_client
```

How do I create a mongo_client with a listener and with a connection string (uri)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code you commented-out is correct:

```
my_mongo_client = MongoClient(connString, event_listeners=[CommandLogger()])
```

Is something not working as expected when you try that?

Comment: I have not tried that statement yet. I previously had two separate statements (one with ConnString and the subsequent statement with event_listener. I was not sure what the right format was. Will be trying this one statement with both connString and event_listener.

Comment: yes, it works! One can add more connString and eventListener to MongoClient.